# count number of 0 in each row and build a new column in r

Tags: r

```
q <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
q1 <- c( 5, 0, 3, 3, 2)
q2 <- c( 4, 5, 5, 3, 2)
q3 <- c( 5, 0, 5, 0, 1)
q4 <- c( 0, 5, 5, 0, 2)
q5 <- c( 0, 0, 2, 0, 1)

k <- data.frame(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5)

  q q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
1 a  5  4  5  0  0 
2 b  0  5  0  5  0
3 c  3  5  5  5  2
4 d  3  3  0  0  0
5 e  2  2  1  2  1
```

I have a table k like this. Now I want to add a new column in this table. The value of the new column is based on the number of "0" of each row(it means I want to count the number of 0 in each row). Could anyone help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: Use `k$newcolumn <- rowSums(k==0)`

Comment: Thanks a lot akrun